# What's the generic name for this threaded/decorative "stem cap" on a Delta threadless steer tube extender

Tags: parts, replacement, stem, terminology

I picked up one of these Delta threadless stem risers / steer tube extenders so I could try out different handle bars heights on my gravel bike without going through a bunch of stems (since shops near me aren't open for a proper bike fit).

[image]

I got it used and really cheap, but it's missing the plastic threaded "stem cap" (see picture). It's not a functional stem cap, per se, as the stem cap bolt actually threads through down inside by the clamp. I guess it's really more of a dust cover, and it threads into the top of the unit instead of being held in place by a bolt. The guy I got it from said it's a generic part that should be easy to replace. But I can't really figure out what it's called so I can order one online. The manufacture has not been helpful thus far.

There's a good chance I'll replace this setup with a proper riser stem once I figure out where I want my bars, so I'm more asking out of curiosity than an immediate need.

Comment: Just to do due diligence, you do know you cannot use these things on a carbon steerer tube, right?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus: Why not? Looks like it clamps to the tube in exactly the same way a stem would.

Comment: @Michael there is increased leverage on the steerer tube

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus: Yes, but I don’t see why the steerer tube material should play a role in that. An aluminium tube can be just as weak as a carbon one. In the end, considering you can have a 44cm wide (or even wider) handlebar, I’m not sure a few cm extension play a significant role at all.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [installation instructions](https://cdn.accentuate.io/4048700047473/9453005078641/TD3318_Instructions_200619-v1592837221033.pdf) the manufacturer calls this a "dust cover cap."  As you note, this is *not* a headset or stem cap since it doesn't mechanically engage with the stem to preload the bearings.

A [Google image search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=simg:CAQStQIJcVIUN3qBFUcaqQILELCMpwgaYgpgCAMSKKsSshK2EqwStxKrHfUfwQatEq8S9DLzMsYznTPNJvoy-TKbM7E2xzMaMF3eExAKkDa0SSKfExOgZjzrq2sO5fIu16Vq2LEIxcxZ8hjgLyilTwcqzNQqm9a1XyAEDAsQjq7-CBoKCggIARIEznK_1JgwLEJ3twQkaoQEKHQoKZ3VuIGJhcnJlbNqliPYDCwoJL20vMDJ6bjU0CiAKDXNvY2tldCB3cmVuY2japYj2AwsKCS9tLzA0c2ZzNwoaCgdyYXRjaGV02qWI9gMLCgkvbS8wMmJtOW4KKQoWbWV0YWx3b3JraW5nIGhhbmQgdG9vbNqliPYDCwoJL20vMDd2YzR2ChcKBXJpZmxl2qWI9gMKCggvbS8wNmM1NAw&q=1+1+8+inch+to+1+inch+stem&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGkeOrpNzqAhUJHc0KHT9zAxAQwg4oAHoECAkQKA) for the image you included found a bunch of pages on Amazon describing this as a "Delta Cycle stem raiser," and I found the instructions on the [Delta Cycle page](https://designbydelta.com/collections/bike-accessories/products/alloy-stem-raiser).

Unfortunately, it [*doesn't* seem to be a generic part](https://www.google.com/search?q=bicycle+stem+riser+extender+%22dust+cap%22); I couldn't find a single instance of it being sold individually.  Perhaps you could bodge something with a normal headset cap.

Comment: Thanks! Never occurred to me to do an image search. Somehow the manufacturer's website never turned up when I was searching for the actual product either. Found the replacement part cap on their website.

Comment: @MikeyC And checking their website for replacement parts is something that didn't occur to me. <facepalm/> :)